# How corectly import Vue in store file?

Tags: vuejs3, vuex, vite

Why do I get this error in my console from the code below?

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue.js?v=338c01cb' does not provide an export named 'default' (at index.js?t=1695292417407:1:8)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

let store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{},
    mutations:{},
    actions:{},
    getters:{}
});

export default store;
// this my store dile



import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './style.css'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'
import router from './router'
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont'


createApp(App)
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .mount('#app');
//  this main.js
```